# updating datastore entity from different REST endpoints

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

let us assume that I have an entity of kind Employee with following properties and initial values:

```
Employee{Name : "Baqir", employeeID: "1234", requestID: "123456" , status : "INITIATED"}
```

***Please note that I can not use query by entity key to obtain strong consistent results because for this case we do not have entity key.***

from app engine backend we have integrated firebase to send notifications to employees. when notification arrived on employee's android phone , our android app hit rest endpoint1 using android background service to update the status from INITIATED to DELIVERED. when employee click on notification our android app opens android camera and capture employees front face and send compressed image to server using REST endpoint2. There is another endpoint3 which saves the high quality of same captured facial image using android background service.

**REST Endpoint 1 :**

1- load the entity using filter(employeeID) and filter(requestID)
  2- update the status to DELIVERED
  3- save the entity
4- send the success result to android client.

*updated entity from  endpoint1 should be like:*

```
Employee{Name : "Baqir", employeeID: "1234", requestID: "123456" , status : "DELIVERED"}
```

**REST Endpoint2:**
1- load the entity using filter(employeeID) and filter(requestID)
2- store the captured face to cloud storage and save the download URL.
3-update the status to "COMPLETED"
4- save the entity
5- send the success result to android client

*updated entity from endpoint2 should be like:*

```
Employee{Name : "Baqir", employeeID: "1234", profilePic: " cloud storage download URL",requestID: "123456" , status : "COMPLETED"}
```

**REST Endpoint3:**
1- load the entity using filter(employeeID) and filter(requestID)
2- store the captured face high quality image to cloud storage and save the download URL.
4- save the entity
5- send the success result to android client

*updated entity from endpoint3 should be like:*

```
Employee{Name : "Baqir", employeeID: "1234", profilePic: " cloud storage download URL",  HQprofilePic: " cloud storage download URL", requestID: "123456" , status : "COMPLETED"}
```

*Problem:*
Android client always executes endpoint1 first then endpoint2 then endpoint3 and receives success result from all the endpoints.
But sometimes  the final updated entity in datastore is the entity updated by endpoint1.

After executing endpoint 1,2,3, final entity in the datastore is :

```
 Employee{Name : "Baqir", employeeID: "1234", requestID: "123456" , status : "DELIVERED"}
```

for some cases final entity is the result of endpoint1 and endpoint3. i.e

```
Employee{Name : "Baqir", employeeID: "1234", requestID: "123456" , HQprofilePic: " cloud storage download URL", status : "DELIVERED"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could, in all endpoints, replace `load the entity using filter(employeeID) and filter(requestID)` (which is eventually consistent) with:

1. obtain the entity key with a [keys_only query](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#projection_queries) using filter(employeeID) and filter(requestID)
2. load the entity by key lookup (always consistent)

You just need to be aware of the delay between the initial creation of the entity with the respective employeeID and requestID and when it becomes visible in step 1 (i.e. when the index for that query is updated) - until that happens you won't be able to get the entity key.

Comment: ,Thanks for the answer. I modified my datastore queries as you said, What if rest endpoint2 and rest endpoint3 reads the same entity (i.e. initial state of entity with INITIATED state  ) and now the endpoint which will save the entity at last will be the final state of entity with updated values. I think i need partial update kind of thing or transaction across the endpoints or I should provide some delay to endpoint3 so that endpoint2 can complete it works first.Please suggest some alternatives.

Comment: There is no partial update in the datastore. To prevent such cases you should have all entity updates done in transactions - one such update would then fail due to collision. You'd probably need to have some logic to force transaction failure in case the order is wrong. The transaction retries would eventually take care of things happening in the desired order. You may need to account for these retries in the client code as well (an update from the android client may not happen right away, for example).

Comment: I do not want to fail update due to collision, I have to update the entity from two different endpoints. Also we can not change the client code for now because its already deployed in the field. What if I put some delay at endpoint3 before reading the entity? It will give some more time to endpoint2 to finish it work. Will it be suitable?

Comment: Colissions are normal - they're exactly the cases in which you currently get the unexpected values - you shouldn't be updating the entity in such conditions, you need to pull the new version of the entity and re-run the update logic - exactly how handling the collisions work.Personally I wouldn't rely on delays (sooner or later things will stop working), but you might get away with them for a while if you manage to find good enough values.